# Symfony pre_submit change field order

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Given the following form type how can I render my second field before submit?
I tried with `$form->remove` but I would always get this error:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty
```

Not really sure how to fix this one.

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('survey', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => SurveyManager::class,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'field-change',
            ],
        ])
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [

        ])
        ->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $data = $event->getData();
                $modifier = $data['survey'];
                $form->add('headquarter', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => HeadQuarterManager::class,
                    'query_builder' => function (HeadQuarterManagerRepository $er) use ($modifier) {
                        return $er->getHeadquarter($modifier);
                    },
                ]);
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'render before submit'? Is it javascript that should do that trick? If so, just add a class (like `hidden`) that initially hides the button and let jQuery show it before submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony's Form component do not support rearranging form's fields. They talked about this feature on issue [#5827](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5827) and [#11241](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/11241).

You could try to remove field `submit` in EventListener, then add `headquerter` and also `submit` (yes, once again). But I am not sure this will be work.

Another solution is install [IvoryOrderedFormBundle](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryOrderedFormBundle). It adds new option in form fields: `position`.

Comment: yes i saw those issues on github and i was like i hope they put it in 3.0 :)) then i noticed they didn't =D. also i saw IvoryOrderedFormBundle but wasn't sure if i should use it =D. i tried removing and adding it again but it didn't work i always get the above error :D

Answer (score 1):

the solution that i used was to remove the submit button from class type and manually add it in the template then use {{ form_rest(form) }} before the submit button and it will render it ok.